# Check if function within another function is called with jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a test that needs to check for a function being called within another function attached to a button with jest and enzyme. I have both functions mocked out, but don't know how to attach one to another.

My component looks like the following:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    handleButton () {
        console.warn('Clicked!')
        this.context.anotherFunction()
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                My Component
                <button class='my-button' onClick={handleButton}>My Button</button>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

I want to check that both `onClick` and `this.context.anotherFunction` are called when the button is clicked. This is what my current test looks like:

```js
  test.only('should test MyComponent button', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />)
    const anotherFunction = jest.fn()
    wrapper.instance().context = { anotherFunction }

    wrapper.instance().handleButton = () => {
      jest.fn()
      // How to simulate a call to anotherFunction???
      // wrapper.instance().context.anotherFunction()
    }
    wrapper.find('.my-button').simulate('click')
    expect(wrapper.instance().showCancelModal).toHaveBeenCalled() // Passes
    expect(wrapper.instance().context.showModal).toHaveBeenCalled() // Fails
  })
```

How can I mock the call of `anotherFunction` in the mocked version of `handleButton`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is [jest.spyOn()](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

That allows you to monitor calls to a function without actually mocking it. So what will be able to do is:

```
 test.only('should test MyComponent button', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />)
    const anotherFunction = jest.fn()
    wrapper.instance().context = { anotherFunction }

    const handleButton = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'handleButton');

    wrapper.find('.my-button').simulate('click')
    // your tests:
    expect(handleButton).toHaveBeenCalled() // Passes
    // Instead of checking "wrapper.instance().context.anotherFunction"
    // you can directly check if anotherFunction was called
    expect(anotherFunction).toHaveBeenCalled() // Fails
  })
```